# How to give users hint about various buttons and other actions like google keep with ripple effect, without using any third party library

Tags: android, material-design, rippledrawable, google-keep

[image: Want to make it like this, so that user will know what are the actions these buttons going to perform]

Want to make it like this, so that user will know what are the actions these buttons going to perform

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to implement this yourself, which I doubt, there's a ton of libraries that already do this. Here's a [list of them](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/198). I personally have used [this one](https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView) for one of my projects and found it pretty good.

> Also, on Android arsenal site (the first link) you can find almost any Android library you can ever need.

Comment: Yeah but Wanted to do this circular reveal animation on my own, pointing to the views specified, libraries I can find anytime @Vucko

Comment: You didn't specify that in the question. You said you wanted to show the users what everything is doing. Not that you wanted to write it from scratch. anyway, nobody is going to write a step-by-step tutorial here.

Comment: Right, no would give steps, just wanted to get a hint only. Anyway Thanks

Comment: @DeepakRathi : Download any of the library and try to customize and understand its code. that will be better way what you want to get. You will be able to do it by yourself and also get some help with what to do next

Comment: Try to go for the methods responsible for that particular effect and make it customized as per your need

Comment: Thanks @DeepPatel , i got it that its circular reveal animation, i am trying to find out how it anchor to the view(button) and cut out that portion only. I'll look and understand other libraries code. thanks for the suggestion